# How to write unit test by mocking, when you have zero arg:constructors

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, jmockit, jmock

I was trying to write unit test using jmocks and junit. (My Project uses core java- no frameworks-) I could not write unit test for some of my classes, by mocking external dependencies, when dependencies were initialized in a a no arg-constructor.

As i cannot provide the actual code, trying to explain the scenario by an example

```
public interface Apple {

String variety();

}
```

Implementation.

```
public class MalgovaApple implements Apple {

  @Override
  public String variety() {
         return "Malgova";

  }

}
```

Class to be tested

```
public class VarietyChecker {
private Apple apple;

VarietyChecker(){
this.apple = new MalgovaApple();
// instead of new, a factory method is used in actual application
}

public String printAppleVariety(){
    String variety = apple.variety();
    if(variety.length() < 3){
       System.out.println("Donot use Code names- Use complete names");
       return "bad";
        }
       return "good";
}
}
```

Junit test using jmock

```
public class VarietyCheckerUnitTest{
Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery();
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void test_VarietyChecker() throws Exception{

    final Apple mockapple = context.mock(Apple.class);

    VarietyChecker printer = new VarietyChecker();
    context.checking(new Expectations(){{
        oneOf(mockapple).variety();will(returnValue("as"));
    }});
    String varietyNameValid = printer.printAppleVariety();

    assertEquals("bad",varietyNameValid);


} }
```

This test fails - Mocking does not work the values "as" is not injected, the test class executes with MalgovaApple ...

Now if we add below constructor to VarietyChecker and use it test case - it gives expected output...

```
public VarietyChecker(Apple apple) {
    super();
    this.apple = apple;
}
```

and in unit test create test class object like
    VarietyChecker printer = new VarietyChecker(mockapple);

Exposing a new constructor just for the purpose of testing is not a good idea. After all it is said that you should not alter the code for testing alone, more than that, i am afraid we have already written "some"(amount) code...

Am i missing something in junit or jmock that can make mocking work even incase of no-arg constructors. Or is this a limitation of simple junit and jmocks and should i migrate to something powerful like **Jmockit** /**PowerMock**

Comment: If you have to alter the code to be able to test it, the code is not well-written.   There's too many tight dependencies on other things for it to work well.  That said, I can't say that migrating wholesale to Mockito will fix your issues; this is one of many, I'm sure.

Comment: @Makoto I object to your first sentence. It is a mantra set forth by unit-testing die-hards that discourages honest evaluation of the value of a test. I used to believe it myself, but that was before I realized there are No Silver Bullets. The reality is that writing good tests and understanding the feedback they give you is as much a skill and an art as writing good code, and it is a skill that's also difficult to master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider two choices.

1. Use a constructor parameter as you describe.

   In this case, you're not "exposing a new constructor just for the purpose of testing". You're making your class more flexible by allowing callers to use a different factory implementation.
2. Don't mock it.

   In this case, you are declaring that it never makes sense to use a different factory. Sometimes this is okay. At that point, the question changes, though. Instead of, "How do I mock this?" your question is now, "What am I gaining from writing this test?" You might not be gaining much of anything, and it might not make much sense to write the test at all.

   If you don't mock it and decide a unit test is still worth it, then you should be asserting on other aspects of the code. Either an end state or some output. In this case, the factory call becomes an implementation detail that's not appropriate for mocking.

   It's important not to fall for a "unit test everything" mentality. That is a recipe for Test-induced Design Damage. Evaluate your tests on a case by case basis, deciding whether they're providing you any real value or not. Not writing a unit test is a valid option and is even appropriate at times, even if it's option you try very hard to avoid.

Only you can make a determination which one makes the most sense in this case. From the the fact that this is a factory object we're talking about, I'd probably lean toward the former.

Comment: There is a third choice (though not a good one): use reflection in the unit test to dynamically set the `apple` member variable in `VarietyChecker`

Comment: @neuronaut I thought about the existence of such hacks when I posted, but couldn't think of a better way to present it. You inspired a small modification, though; I hope you approve. ;)

Comment: I am not sure how clear is my example to the real case - Actually my VarietyChecker is a Jersey WebService class and a no: arg constructor loads some property files...An argument constructor is of no use other than in test flows.@jpmc26 your second point is a good one...I was in a test everything mode..but i still requires to test in some cases

Comment: @searchingforPerfection I think you should mock in that case. By allowing the factory to be passed in, you are simplifying your class and increasing flexibility. It makes sense to avoid tying a class to a specific configuration loader. This is a good way to isolate the rest of your code from external systems (file system, database, external web service). I would, however, probably *not* unit test the internals of the configuration loader itself, though.

Comment: @searchingforPerfection Actually, rather than a mock, I might advocate for a *stub* here. You're not trying to test that the configuration loader was called correctly. You're trying to test that your class, given certain data from the configuration loader, behaves correctly later. So while I *would* make it a constructor argument, I *wouldn't* assert on the factory object you pass in. (The distinct between mocks and stubs is more a distinction of how you use them, imo, than in implementation. So you don't necessarily need new tools for that.)